# LaTex problems after SSL installation

Tags: environments

We just installed SSL on our custom site where we have many math formulas in LaTeX. Now the formulas don't come up properly. Instead we get the original coding, such as

```
 \(\begin{align}\sqrt{27x - 45} = x + 3\end{align}\).
```

Is there a plugin or some other method we can use to get the LaTeX interpreted properly?

Comment: Incidentally, what is "SSL"? I assume it doesn't mean "secure socket layer", or does it?

Comment: @Mico I suspect it does (and this is a mathjax config issue)

Comment: Yes, it means secure socket layer.

Comment: In that case, please tell us more about your system'e LaTeX setup. Is it part of s full TrX distribution, is it some form of MathJax, or something else?

Comment: As a guess, there may be some document content (either a Javascript file, an image of the rendered equation, or maybe both) that is still being served over http, and the browser may be refusing to use the http content on an otherwise https page. If there's still an http version of the page, see if that still works correctly.

Comment: I'm not in contact with the programmer right now, but I took this line out of the source, which I think might be relevant:    <script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I understand from elsewhere that SSL can break LaTeX if you use the standard mathjax file, but perhaps that's no longer true.

Comment: I don't think there's been a problem since 2014, and [MathJax's Getting Started page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#secure-access-to-the-cdn) indicates you can use https. Regardless, MathJax questions aren't on topic here (it uses a TeX-like syntax, but not a TeX engine).

Comment: That looks like an in-line math with an embedded align environment. Does that even make sense?

Comment: @gwh5 mathjax is not tex based it is javascript.